# In Bootstrap Modal Popup Tab order not moving to Datatable Header?

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal, twitter-bootstrap-2

> In Bootstrap Modal Popup Tab order not moving to Datatable Header?
>   Without Datatable ,In modal popup shift+tab order is going out of the popup dialog. It needs to be inside of the Modal dialog.

Comment: Can you paste your code??, adding tabindex="-1" in the modal wrapper it should do the trick

Comment: I added the tabindex but eventhough the issue occurs,<div class="modal container fade" id="dialog1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true"> In MVC I am calling the popup content as a partial view. @ppollono

Answer (score 0):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ppollono/25vmg3bb/), try adding tabindex to the `modal` element

Answer (score 0):

All of the answers and comments are wrong in here. This "bug" is also occurs in antd-Modal. Somehow, shift+tab combination goes outside of the modal and you can select and type(in input elements for example) everything behind the modal.

For now, seems like there is no fix for this.